# Run code after tests with shoulda context

Tags: ruby-on-rails, unit-testing, automated-tests, factory-bot, shoulda

With the standard tests there's a **setup** block that runs before each test. Is there something similar that we can run 'after' each test?

The reason i'm asking is that my tests make requests to an outside API and i need to perform cleanup on that when the tests are done.

Comment: Are you using `rspec`?

Comment: Factory Girl + Shoulda. But i guess the answer may work with both.

Comment: I meant what testing framework you are using, one that comes with rails itself or `rspec` that most people use. Factory Girl and Shoulda   can be used with both.

Comment: standard rails testing